# Money transfer via Android/iOS app using credit cards

Tags: android, ios, paypal, payment

I'm building a restaurant application where users can order food. I currently only give the option to pay by cash when the food arrives, however I want to add the possibility of paying by Visa/MasterCard/Any other card.

I know I can use PayPal, but what happens if the restaurant doesn't have a PayPal account?

And is there any way to transfer the money securely directly from the card to the restaurant's bank account, just as a default Point of Sale would do?
Of course a library or way would have to check the card's validity first.

Thank you in advance,
Basel

Comment: You need something to acquire the transaction and provide the credit card merchant services. You can't just "transfer money". The restaurants existing point--of-sale would be set up,with their bank or other credit card transaction processor. You could use PayPal Here or perhaps you could look at Braintree but I don't know if they support this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I think this library will do the trick](https://stripe.com/docs)

but im not sure, I just started reserching on this mater and I dont know much about money transfers and stuff.

or use this [Veritrans SDK](https://veritrans.co.id/)

hope it helps =)